Show where objects talk to woman
Looking for a television show which I watched around 2013, though I believe it was at least a few years old at that point. It was a comedy. The main point of each episode was inanimate objects would start talking to the main character, a woman in their early twenties. I believe it was set around Niagara Falls, and that she lived in a trailer that was boring on the outside but fairly colorful and comfortable looking on the inside.
In one episode her friend asks her to go to an native american reservation where the friend is trying to claim ancestry to get some money from the casino. The main plot of the episode was that someone important had died, and needed replaced, their grandson was the likely candidate, but to do so was suppose to identify an object that belonged to their grandmother (the person who had died), and a feather was suppose to touch them (?). They had trouble doing this. Meanwhile objects were talking to the main character telling her which one it was, and a feather was floating around her, which she tried to subtly blow away. The episode resolved with the person to take the place of the person who died being someone that the main character's sister went to school with and had a rivalry with.
I'm told that there was a second season that was written, but never aired. In that season apparently the main character's therapist had her committed though not for her own good, rather to take advantage of her ability to hear objects talking to her.

This is Wonderfalls (2004).

The show centers on Jaye Tyler (Caroline Dhavernas), a recent Brown University graduate with a philosophy degree, who holds a dead-end job as a sales clerk at a Niagara Falls gift shop. Jaye is the reluctant participant in conversations with various animal figurines – a wax lion, brass monkey, stuffed bear, and mounted fish, among others – which direct her via oblique instructions to help people in need





Beat me to it.  I had link in hand. :-D

Missed it by that much ...

Beat me to it by 4 hours. Underrated show.

I liked it. The show that launched Lee Pace's career, too.

That was Wonderfalls.  It was set in Niagara falls, where various objects would talk to the main character and tell her to do things.  It usually resulted in something good happening for somebody.
